# Using JavaScript to wrap multiple hashtags in links

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, replace

I'm banging my head against the wall with this, after a good few hours of Googling, searching Stack Exchange and trial and error I haven't been able to figure it out. Any help would be hugely appreciated!

I'm trying to replace hashtags in a paragraphs with links. I've been able to do this by using the following:

```
var str = $('.item p').html(),
  regex = /(?:\s|^)(?:#(?!\d+(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|$)/gi;

function replacer(){
  var replacementString = $.trim(str.match( regex )[0]);
  return ' <a href="https://www.example.com/'+ replacementString +'" target="_blank">' + replacementString + '</a>';
}
$('.item p').html( str.replace( regex , replacer ) );
```

This replaces the hashtags successfully but as I'm using [0] then if there are multiple hashtags then it only replaces hashtag with the text of the first one. Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TxVw8/1/) with what I have so far. I need to try to figure out how to replace each hashtag with a link to that particular hashtag.

I'm not sure whether I should be using a loop and incrementing the [0] or whether I'm going in completely the wrong direction here and there's an easier way to do this.

If anyone has any pointers than I'd really appreciate it!

John

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple change like this on your function will do what you want:

```
function replacer(hash){
  var replacementString = $.trim(hash);
  return ' <a href="https://www.example.com/'+ replacementString +'" target="_blank">' + replacementString + '</a>';
}
```

In you case, there's no need to do a match inside the `replacer` function invoked by `.replace`, as the first parameter of that function is already the current matched substring.

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/zq7sF/)**

EDIT: If you want to match hashtags without spaces in between, you can modify your regex a little:

```
(?:|^)(?:#(?!\d+(?:\s|$)))(\w+)(?=\s|#|$)
```

**[UPDATED JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/zq7sF/)**

Comment: Awesome! Works like a charm! Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it.

A quick question just to help me understand what's happening here - how is the 'hash' variable being passed to the 'replacer' function?

Comment: @John, no problem, I'm glad it worked out for you. The `hash` variable (or whatever you want to name it) is passed to replacer with a predefined set of variables, you can see more about this **[on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter)**

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now! Thanks a lot for the link, and again for your help.

Comment: Hey.. this won't handle hashtags without spaces in between, like: #hashtag#anotherone. These are valid hashtags in Instagram for example...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using pure javascript:

```
String.prototype.parseHashtag = function() {
    return this.replace(/[#]+[A-Za-z0-9-_]+/g, function(t) {
        var tag = t.replace("#","")
        return '<a href="https://www.example.com/'+ tag + '" target="_blank">' + tag + '</a>';
    });
};

var input = "some randomg string #something some text";

console.log(input.parseHashtag()); // some randomg string <a href="https://www.example.com/something" target="_blank">something</a> some text
```

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UN88b/)

Comment: Thanks Tom, this works great too! Darkajax had the exact solution I was looking for but this is awesome too. Thanks so much for your help!