# Is it possible with CSS to change the backcolor of some text starting with a character

Tags: css

I am creating a twitter like application. Users can post their comments and enter hash tags. Once they post it, I show the messages inside a div. Is it possible that I add a rule using CSS, which ensures that any word within that div which starts with '#' character, should have a bigger font and a different back color?

Comment: Unfortunately CSS doesn't have the ability to affect strings in that manner. It's definitely possible using JS; you'd probably be best to use a regular expression to find the hashtags, wrap them in a `span`, then apply some CSS to that span element

Comment: Here's a question which does exactly that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769450/using-javascript-to-wrap-multiple-hashtags-in-links

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: Thank you quick help.